gfortran performs unsafe math optimizations of cos(atan(x))
I'm researching an issue where gfortran returns in rare cases different result depending on optimization level even with compile options -fno-fast-math and -fno-unsafe-math-optimizations so that result should not depend on optimization level. I tested this with gfortran-11.2.1, gfortran-11.4.1 (both RedHat) and gfortran-14.2 (godbolt). For reproducible results I also need to use OpenLibM math library instead of gcc math library, so I will continue discussion on godbolt disassembly.
The result difference comes from the calculation y = cos(atan(x)) which is replaced by y = 1/sqrt(1+x^2) for -O1 or higher: compile
double precision function foo(x)
implicit none
double precision, intent(in) :: x
foo = cos(atan(x))
end function foo

with gfortran -c file.f90 -O1, see https://godbolt.org/z/c9b4rvhdW and check created code: no call to cos or atan, but instead sqrt is used. If -O0 is used the atan and cos functions are used.
From documentation I would expect that -fno-fast-math or -fno-unsafe-math-optimizations should disable this optimization, but it looks like these have no effect on gfortran. Only -fno-tree-forwprop disables this optimizations so that same results as with -O0 are returned.
For gcc C compiler behaves as expected: for the C variant of same code (https://godbolt.org/z/E7Mzh6Taq) this optimization is only done by compiler if -ffast-math is specified, but not for default -O1.
Is using -O0 or '-fno-tree-forwprop` the only option to disable these math optimizations? I'd like to be sure to get identical results for all optimization levels but keeping performance as good as possible.

Short answer, no.  A slightly longer answer, GCC offers the -fno-builtin option, but gfortran does not honor that option.  One could hack gfortran to honor it and submit a patch.  As an aside, you don't need to use godbolt to see what gfortran is doing.  Try the -fdump-tree-optimized option when using optimization.

Follow-up comment.  What is the domain of x?  Does accuracy of result matter?

Can't test now, but does splitting it into two statements and introducing a temporary make any difference?

@IanBush, The answer to whether splitting into tmp = atan(x) ; foo = cos(tmp) makes a difference is maybe.  It depends on how one declares tmp.

@steve: Accuracy is uncritical in my application, reproducibility is most important. I had already tried -fdump-tree-optimized and -fdump-tree-all which helped me to find the only option that really helped here (`-fno-tee-forwprop')

@IanBush: in the original code the two statements were separated with several lines in between. Adding a function call (print) in between disabled this optimization which took me even more time to check for invalid memory access and similar issues.

What prevents you from redefining built-in functions with standard Fortran language tools? Define a module and use it everywhere, especially since you are going to use the OpenLibM implementation.
module c_replace_builtins
    implicit none

    interface 
        function atan(x) bind(c)
            use iso_c_binding
            real(c_double) atan
            real(c_double), value :: x
        end function

        function cos(x) bind(c)
            use iso_c_binding
            real(c_double) cos
            real(c_double), value :: x
        end function
    end interface
end module c_replace_builtins

program test
    implicit none

    integer :: i
    double precision :: x

    do i = 0, 10
        x = 10.d0**(-i)
        print *, x, foo(x) - cos(atan(x))
    end do

contains
    double precision function foo(x)
        use c_replace_builtins
                ! We use it only here so that the built-in
                ! functions in the main program do not change.

        implicit none
        double precision, intent(in) :: x
        foo = cos(atan(x))
    end function foo
end program test

P.S.
To prevent optimization of calls to built-in functions, you can do the same and define an external module that overrides the built-in functions. This will probably be no less efficient than using an intermediate volatile variable, and most likely it will be more efficient.
f_replace_builtins.f90:
module f_builtins
    implicit none

contains
    double precision function builtin_atan(x)
        double precision, intent(in) :: x
        builtin_atan = atan(x)
    end function

    double precision function builtin_cos(x)
        double precision, intent(in) :: x
        builtin_cos = cos(x)
    end function
end module f_builtins

module f_replace_builtins
    use f_builtins

    implicit none

contains
    double precision function atan(x) result(res)
        double precision, intent(in) :: x
        res = builtin_atan(x)
    end function

    double precision function cos(x) result(res)
        double precision, intent(in) :: x
        res = builtin_cos(x)
    end function
end module f_replace_builtins


Thanks, in combination with OpenLibM where I really want the compiler not to do any internal magic with these math functions using explicit interfaces is the best idea. A compiler flag to ensure this would be safer, but this is not yet supported by gfortran.

It is a good thing that accuracy is unimportant.  Testing 10 million values of x in the interval [0:137] shows that 8984174 (89.84%) of the results for cos(atan(x)) have a ULP exceeding 2 ULP if the optimization is prevented.  The maximum observed ULP was 129.42, which is equivalent to 5 wrong trailing digits.  If the count threshold is increased to 100 ULP, then one finds 144035 (1.44%) values that exceed 100 ULP.
With the optimization only 26 results exceed 2 ULP.
With that stated, one can prevent the optimization without the use of a compiler option.  foo() can be written as
double precision function foo(x)
   implicit none
   double precision, intent(in) :: x
   double precision, volatile :: tmp
   tmp = atan(x)
   foo = cos(tmp)
end function foo

The volatile attribute tells the compiler that the value of tmp may change by some means outside of the control of the compiler between the time that atan(x) was evaluated and when tmp is referenced in cos(tmp).  The compiler will reload tmp from memory.

Thanks, I never considered that this optimization could improve accuracy and is not only performance related. But it would be good if gfortran would better consider the same compiler flags as gcc/g++ in such cases.

Ahhh, volatile. Never thought of that. But all in all I find this a bit depressing. The most reproducible answer should be the accurate one, I do find it strange that even on finding about the inaccuracy the desire is for the "wrong" one.

@IanBush , desires can be different, for example, when implementing double-double arithmetic: r0 = a*b; r1 = ieee_fma(a, b, -r0), only reproducibility is required.

@bbu, gcc/g++ must consider that x may exceed |x| > 1.  Fortran prohibits such an argument, which allows the compiler to assume that |x| <= 1 and hence perform the transformation for accuracy.  If one writes the equivalent C code with return (cos(atan(x))); and compiles with -ffast-math, you get the optimization performed by gfortran.  The argument prohibition might be loosened with an IEEE_ARITHMETIC intrinsic module is in play, but I would need to go re-read Fortran 2023, Sec. 17.

@IanBush, it's an interesting exercise in FP arithmetic.  atan(x) for x in the interval [0,137] on my system has a max ULP of 0.836.  In the interval [0,pi/2], cos(y) has a max ULP of 0.752.  But, when combined as cos(atan(x)) the inaccuracy of atan(x) for large x gets amplified by cos() because it is approaching 0.
